# @Autowire doesn't work after moving subpackage to new package

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two base packages in my Spring application - `com.company.myappmonitor` and `com.company.myappcommon`.

Inside of `com.company.myappmonitor`, I have subpackages `com.company.myappmonitor.dao` and `com.company.myappmonitor.repository` .

I used Intellij Refactor > Move to move `com.company.myappmonitor.dao` and `com.company.myappmonitor.repository` to `com.company.myappcommon` - so they are now located at `com.company.myappcommon.dao` and `com.company.myappcommon.repository` . I'm able to build the Spring application successfully.

Once I move these subpackages to `com.company.myappcommon` - I am receiving errors that one of my `@Autowired` annotations is no longer working.  The error is

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field myVersionsRepository in com.company.myappmonitor.service.myVersionsServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.company.myappcommon.repository.myVersionsRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.myappcommon.repository.myVersionsRepository' in your configuration.
```

`@Autowired` was working before I moved dao and repository subpackages.

I'm using Spring java configuration and annotations to set up my services in my Spring context.  My myVersionsRepository looks like

```
package com.company.myappcommon.repository;

import ...

@Transactional
@Repository
public interface myVersionsRepository extends CrudRepository<myVersions, String>, myVersionsRepositoryCustom {
```

My myVersionsServiceImpl looks like

```
package com.company.myappmonitor.service;

import ...

@Service(value = "myVersionsServiceImpl")
public class myVersionsServiceImpl implements myVersionsService {

    @Autowired
    myVersionsRepository myVersionsRepository;
```

My Configuration class looks like

```
package com.company.myappmonitor.config;

import ...

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.company")
public class AppConfig {
```

I'm thinking that it is a problem with my `@ComponentScan` basePackages.  I've tried

```
@ComponentScan("com.company")
@ComponentScan("com.company.myappmonitor", "com.company.myappcommon")
and
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.myappmonitor", "com.company.myappcommon"})
```

None of these worked.  Any ideas why I'm getting this error?  Thank you!

Comment: Just to test: move your `@Configuration` class to `com.company` package and remove any values from `@ComponentScan` annotation. Spring will scan packages starting from `com.company`. is this working?

Comment: Did you move your 'myVersionsRepositoryCustom' interface implemantation too? Spring could not find its implemantation may be?

Comment: barbakini - yes i did the Impl too - but the method I needed was  findByTheId() in the myVersionsRepository interface.  This was working before the move to com.company.myappcommon

Comment: Ivan - that didn't work.  Same error.

Comment: Did you check if your [spring repository instances config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances) was updated accordingly after the refactoring?

Comment: Morfic- well these are CrudRepositories.  But I did try @EnableJpaRepositories in my configuration class and it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my app to build, @Autowired working.

The problem is for some reason @Repository components are not scanned

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/95749-repository-component-is-not-scanned-please-help

I actually was not using my repository classes that much, I just deleted the com.company.myappcommon.repository subpackage entirely and the app built fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "com.company.myappcommon.*"to your `compontScan` basePackages. such as:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.company.myappcommon.*","com.company"})
public class AppConfig{
...
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I get the same error.  What is very strange about this problem is that - in com.company.myappcommon, I have a subpackage com.company.myappcommon.model - with persistence @Entity classes that are successfully found by component scan, while my dao and repository subpackages are not able to be found.

Comment: I'm not clear about your question.I think your question is spring can't find your `myVersionsRepository` bean.Generally the `@ComponentScan` can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue. I added below code and it's working.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanPackages = "your package")
```

Check official site for reference.

https://www.java2novice.com/issues/spring-boot-not-scanning-components/